# RTK Query UseLazyQuery and Typescript: how to get the correct type from hook argument

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, rtk-query

I need to create a react hook that accepts a RTK Query UseLazyQuery function (from any endpoint), apply a debounce to it and return the trigger function and results.

Everything is working as expected but I can't manage to get the correct type to the data returned by it.

As "UseLazyQuery" type requires a type for its generic type and I don't know what type it'll be, I set it to "any", but it makes the data to be typed as "any" too.

I need help to get/extract the correct type from the given "UseLazyQuery" function given to the hook and make the returned data have the correct type.

```
export default function useSearch<T extends UseLazyQuery<any>>(lazyQueryFn: T) {
  const [ trigger, results ] = lazyQueryFn()

  const getParamsAndTrigger = async (
    params: ISearchParamsRequest,
    filterParams?: (params: ISearchParamsRequest) => ISearchParamsRequest
  ) => {
    await trigger(filterParams ? filterParams(params) : params, true)
  }

  const debouncedTrigger = useDebouncedFn(getParamsAndTrigger, 1500)

  return [debouncedTrigger, { ...results }] as const
}
```

The "results" const returned by "lazyQueryFn" has the type "UseQueryStateDefaultResult". I need it to have the right data type.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation this days and I came with this approach which fixed it and should help you too:

```
interface ResponseData<V> {
  items: V[];
  cursor: string;
}

export const useGetCursorPaginatedData = <
  V,
  T extends UseLazyQuery<QueryDefinition<any, any, any, ResponseData<V>, any>>
>(
  lazyQuery: T
) => {
  const [trigger] = lazyQuery();

  const { onTriggerAction, isLoading, error } = useAsyncAction();
  const [items, setItems] = useState<V[]>([]);
  const [newCursor, setNewCursor] = useState<string | undefined>();

  const getData = async (isRefresh?: boolean) => {
    const tempList = isRefresh ? [] : items;
    const { data } = await trigger(isRefresh ? undefined : newCursor);
    setItems([...tempList, ...data?.items]);
    setNewCursor(data?.cursor);
  };

  const onLoadMore = useCallback(() => {
    getData();
  }, [newCursor]);

  const onRefresh = () => {
    onTriggerAction(async () => getData(true));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onTriggerAction(getData);
  }, []);

  return {
    items,
    isLoading,
    isError: error != null,
    onLoadMore,
    onRefresh
  };
};
```

And this is how to use it:

```
 const {
    items: dailyTweets,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    onLoadMore,
    onRefresh
  } = useGetCursorPaginatedData<DailyTweet, typeof useLazyGetDailyTweetsQuery>(
    useLazyGetDailyTweetsQuery
  );
```

Basically what you need extra is to define an interface for the QueryDefinition Response, in my case ResponseData and  add one more generic type to function definition that is the type of the returned data in your response.

I hope this will help you.